# C#: How to use a variable like a type - not generic

Tags: c#, types

Suppose I have a class Animal, and several sub-classes, Dog, Cat, Bird, etc.

Now I have a Person, who has an Animal.  She wants to see if the pet store has an animal of the same type.

So I have:

```
Animal sampleAnimal;
List<Animal> listOfAnimals;  // in our hypothetical pet store
```

When I try to do this (in C# 3.5):

```
Type typeWeWant = sampleAnimal.GetType();
foreach (var x in listOfAnimals) {
  if (x is typeWeWant) { // error here
     return true;
  }
}
```

I get the error "typeWeWant is a variable but is used like a type."

Okay.  How do I do this?

Keep in mind, our Person might have a CalicoCat, which is a subclass of Cat, and it should match against Cat.  So using GetType.ToString() won't work.  (Pets are not exactly what's going on in my case - if the code as written worked, I would be fine.  I don't need to test both ways.)

I apologise if this has been asked anywhere already, but all I could find were questions regarding generics, which is not quite the case here.

**EDIT**:  Thank you SO much for both the answers and the "duplicate" link!  These are exactly what I needed and could not find!

Comment: To reproduce your code it would be helpful if you could add a little more code.

Comment: Have you tried in the if to do `x.GetType()`? EDIT: I don't think what you're trying to do is possible in C# 3.5

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Type.IsAssignableFrom` as follows:

```
if (typeWeWant.IsAssignableFrom(x.GetType()))
    return true;
```

This covers both the subclass and type equality cases.

Answer (score 2):

In the if condition use either

```
if (x.GetType() == typeWeWant)
```

or, if you need to find all type of cats, including subclasses of cats

```
if (typeWeWant.IsSubclassOf(x.GetType())
if (x.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeWeWant)
```

Comment: you can't use IsSubclassOf like that. IsSubclassOf is member of Type - so you can use
`x.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeWeWant)`

Comment: @IvanSalo, thanks, forgot it. Edited the answer.

Comment: `This method also returns false if c and the current Type are equal.` from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.issubclassof?view=netframework-4.7.2 (which I doubt is what you want). I think you might be better with `IsAssignableFrom`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
Type typeWeWant = sampleAnimal.GetType();
foreach (var x in listOfAnimals) {
  // with check only by type of typeWeWant
  if (x.GetType() == typeWeWant) {
     return true;
  }
  // depends on your needs you can use one of following
  // will check if typeWeWant is subclass of x
  if (typeWeWant.IsSubclassOf(x.GetType()) {
     return true;
  }
  // will check if x is subclass of typeWeWant
  if (x.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeWeWant)) {
     return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Am... Correct me if I'm wrong, but it will compile, but won't work, because `typeof(typeWeWant)` is `Type`, not an `Animal` or its children.

Comment: Would it perhaps be worth explaining what this check is not **exactly** the same as an `is` check, and how their results might differ?

Comment: to check subclass please use `typeWeWant.IsSubclassOf(x.GetType())` or 
`x.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeWeWant)` depends on your needs

Answer (score -1):

Had a play around and this is what I got working:

```
 Type typeWeWant = sampleAnimal.GetType();
 foreach (var x in listOfAnimals)
 {
     if (typeWeWant.IsInstanceOfType(x))
     {
         return true;
     }
 }
```

This also works:

```
Type typeWeWant = sampleAnimal.GetType();
foreach (var x in listOfAnimals)
{
    if (typeWeWant.IsSubclassOf(x.GetType()))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would have to test against both: IsInstanceOf only tests if it's exactly the same; IsSubclassOf returns false if they are exactly the same class!

Comment: Ahh okay I get you, good spot!